# Does the act of READING data from a contract during a transaction consume gas?

Tags: transactions, fees

If I want to read certain state of a contract while performing my transaction (for instance to make sure no other addresses interacted with that contract within the same block as me), do those actions consume gas? I mean, would that make the transaction more expensive in terms of fees than not reading anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 25 you have all gas cost :

https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf

```
Gcall 700 Paid for a CALL operation
```

So yes it cost gas for every action a smart contract do, but a call is not very expansive. You can read in data to have condition for example.

Comment: Much appreciated, just what I was looking for!